# Valueupdate a computed observable on keyup, but not observable(s) it relies on

Tags: knockout.js

I have a computedObservable which is dependent upon the value of another observable that is tied to a text input.  Like so, where `hasValidAlmUrl` is the computedObservable:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedArchive().almUrl" />
<button type="button" data-bind="enable: hasValidAlmUrl">Test</button>
```

My knockout view model looks like this:

```
function ArchiveViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedArchive = ko.observable(new ArchiveData());
    self.hasValidAlmUrl = ko.computed(function () {
        var almUrl = self.selectedArchive().almUrl();
        if (typeof (almUrl) == 'undefined') return false;
        return almUrl.length > 0;
    }, self);
    ...
};
```

The `hasValidAlmUrl` computedObservable works correctly currently, but I want it to update on the keydown event of the `<input>` instead of when the focus of the `<input>` changes.  I can get this to work by adding a `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` on the `<input>`.

What I don't like about that is that these elements are in a modal.  Behind the modal overlay is a list of entities for which the entity in the populated modal is part of.  When I set the `<input>` to have a `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`, you can see the grid behind the modal changing as the value of the input changes which I think looks bad.

**Is there any way to have a computed observable update on keydown of the observable it's dependent upon BUT not have the dependent observable change on keydown?**

Answer (score 1):

Create a NEW observable to hold your temporary input, and on some event (focus, apply, etc) copy that value into your original observable:

```
self.tmpAlmUrl = ko.observable(); // bind your input to this
self.hasValidAlmUrl = ko.computed(function () {
     return (typeof (self.tmpAlmUrl()) !== 'undefined') && self.tmpAlmUrl().length;
});

// call when about to show the modal
self.onDisplayModal = function () {
    self.tmpAlmUrl(self.selectedArchive().almUrl();
});

// call when you want to "apply" the new url
self.onApplyChanges = function () {
    self.selectedArchive.almUrl(self.tmpAlmUrl());
};
```